# Google Search Console property not visible to added owner

Tags: google-search-console

I have a property A owned by Owner1 who delegates ownership to Owner2.

But that property is not visible to Owner2 on his webmaster console. Though Owner1 continues to see Owner2 as a verified owner (verified by delegation.)

What can be the issue? How can this be solved?

P.S: For those saying to the add property url

If we add the url in property as said above. It is asking to verify the ownership.

Comment: What verification method was used for Owner1?    Is the data for that verification method still in place?